# Eliminate the lists that contains the same elements in Java

Tags: java

```
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
       
        //value, index 
        //hashmap -> easier to access is key 
        for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
            hmap.put(nums[i], i); 
        } 
        
        //System.out.println(hmap.toString());
        
        
        for (int i=0; i<nums.length-1; i++) {
            for (int j=i+1; j<nums.length; j++) {
                int complement = 0-nums[i]-nums[j];  
                if ( hmap.containsKey(complement) &&    ) {
                    List<Integer> ls = new ArrayList<>(); 
                    
                    list.add(ls); 
                    ls.add(nums[i]); 
                    ls.add(nums[j]);
                    ls.add(complement); 
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        return list;
```

I'm trying to solve 3Sum problem from the leetcode (https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/). The output my code generates and the expected output are following.

[image]

How should I fix my code?

I'm trying to get an output of not duplicated arraylist.

Comment: We don't know what "the 3Sum problem from the leetcode" is.

Comment: fair! Added a link.

Comment: Your code currently doesn't verify that `complement` does not correspond to a value that is at position `i` or `j`.